# How to use sink() to save R output in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

Normally, I can use the `sink()` function to redirect R output to a file. For example:

`sink("test.txt")
 cat("Hello World")
 sink()`

However, in Jupyter Notebook (R kernel), using `sink()` did not redirect the printed output and I got nothing in the `test.txt` file. I know that specify filename in `cat("Hello World", file = "test.txt")` can save output and avoid using `sink()` altogether. The problem is that I have hundreds of lines written using `cat()` without specifying filename.

Anyone knows why `sink()` did not work in Jupyter? Is there other alternative way to store output printed in R?

Comment: I don't know that question but ... is it something you can use `capture.output` for instead? (I don't know it will work if `sink` does not, but if it does then you could easily follow `sink()` with `writeLines(...)` if you still need it in an external file.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the cat function itself, if that suffices.

```
f <- file("/tmp/test.txt", open = "wt")
cat <- function(...){
    base::cat(..., file=f)
    }
cat("Hello World\n")
close(f)
```

Comment: It worked for single code cell in the notebook. When I have multiple code cells, it output all my variables in the global environment instead. Why?